# Is there an equivalent for C# (or C++) keyword 'using' for Matlab?

Tags: c#, c++, matlab, keyword, using

All is said in the title.

I modified a function which was using a lot of parameters in order to give it only a structure with all these parameters inside it. Now, I don't want to rewrite everything in the function (param1 to struct.param1) so I would like to put something like 'using struct' which will permit the entire function to get 'param1' from 'struct.param1'

Is this clear or not? English is not my mother language.

Comment: if function is inside the class, then you ommit `this.param1` and say simply `param1`. As far as I know there are no `alias`'es in C# ([using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) is only for namespaces/types), maybe some sort of preprocessor can do this. But in general when you want to do a change without chaning something you can still make a new thing and call old thing in the compartible way: `void newfunc(mystruct struct) { oldfunction(struct.param1, struct.param2, ...); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nasty way of doing so would be

```
function my_using( params )
%
% params should be a struct (NOT an array of struct!)
%
fn = fieldnames( params );
for ii = 1:numel( fn )
    assignin('caller', fn{ii}, params.(fn) );
end
```

Now you can call `my_using` in your function and all params in the struct will be created as variables in the function

Comment: `assignin('caller', fn{ii}, params.(fn{ii}));` maybe?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! That will save me, at least 4 hours of copying/pasting!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be

```
tn = tempname();
save( tn , '-struct', 'params' ); % note the -struct option!
load( tn );
```